# How can I remap the Enter key on a Chromebook?

Tags: keyboard, chromebook, remapping

I have a Chromebook and the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key broke.

It doesn't work at all when pressing it, which of course is quite a bit of an issue. For now, I use an external keyboard, but this is rather annoying when on the road. Can I somehow remap the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key? For instance, making the right <kbd>Shift</kbd> behave as if it were the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key would be really useful.

Comment: There are a few remapping options in Settings but not for Enter.  If something's stuck under the key you could maybe blow it out with compressed air.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the key doesn't seem to be fixable. We have even ordered a new ENTER key and replaced it but to no avail. Any other thoughts on a software-based solution?

Comment: A full Linux install would make it much more configurable.  https://mrchromebox.tech/

Comment: Yes agreed, but unfortunately I have to keep ChromeOS installed... :-( Any options within these constraints?